# Product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am working on a problem and it ask to solve for the product of disjoint cycle from left to right convention. Have I done anything wrong in my attempt?

$$(16527348)\cdot (152468)\cdot( 37 )$$

Starting with $1$: $$1\rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 8$$

so $ ( 18 \cdots )$. Continuing with 8:
$$8\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 5$$
so $( 185\cdots )$
Starting with 5: 
$$5\rightarrow 2  \rightarrow 4$$
so $ (1854)$.
This cycle ends here since 4 is mapped to 1.

Repeating this process the disjoint product cycle is 
$$(1854)(236)(73).$$

Comment: @Human: both right-to-left and left-to-right convention is used in different books. Anyway! @boyinneed; you are right.

Comment: @pGroups, Okie, I don't know about left to right convention. And I think his answer is wrong. $7\rightarrow 7$ not $3$.

Comment: @oh, yes! I checked only first cycle in product, and believed that answer is right.

Comment: @Human: the convention followed by boyinneed is as in Herstein (https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6N2aoMYbYQMC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=i+n+herstein+given+two+permutations&source=bl&ots=5adHM3ljBz&sig=N4pOVx93DERDAJGsFzty_HHsEr4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl3bCSh9LLAhVFj44KHYedDn4Q6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=i%20n%20herstein%20given%20two%20permutations&f=false), whereas, in Contemporary Abstract Algebra-Gallian, it is according to your convention.

Comment: @pGroups, thanks for giving reference to the book. Till now I had followed Gallian that's why I didn't know about this convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you take product from left to right, then your last cycle is wrong.

$7\rightarrow 3$ and then $3\rightarrow 7$ , finally $7\rightarrow 7$

So your final answer will be $$(1854)(236)(7)=(1854)(236)$$